# Is there a way to access emails via IMAP in Blazor WebAssembly

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, blazor, imap

I tried using an IMAP library, but I found out the hard way that the required "System.Security.Cryptography" namespaces have been discontinued since .Net 5 and most (if not all) tutorials online either just show how to send E-Mails via SMTP or they just use another IMAP library that also relies on said namespaces.

Edit: Oh, I just realized that I'm just stupid and put my Service which was handling all the Mail-Stuff in the Frontend instead of the backend, which is why it didn't work

Comment: Try `MailKit` library: https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit#using-imap

Comment: While not free, Mail.dll might be useful. I've used it for over a decade from PowerShell to C# , basic auth to OAuth. https://www.limilabs.com/mail